# Tweepy REST API search query

Tags: rest, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to use the twitter REST API to search for specific tweets. I only want to retrieve tweets that have location enabled, in the city of London, and have coordinates enabled. However, I am unsure how to actually write this in a query.

At the moment, the code I have searches for a single keyword that is entered in text box and returns tweets which contain the given word. For example:

```
searchW = "'"+keyword+"'"
maxTweets = 500  
tweetsPerQry = 100

tweets = api.search(q=searchW, count=tweetsPerQry)
```

Is there anyway I can expand on that query to include the filters that I've mention? I've looked through the documentation but I'm unsure how to structure it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to get the latitude and longitude of the center on london.
You can get if from openstreetmap or googlemap (something like 51.5128,-0.1171).

Refering the documentation at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html you have to use the `geocode` parameter, and add a radius in miles or kilometers.

So to get tweets containing your keyword and geolocated in London within a radius of 2 km :

```
searchW = "'"+keyword+"'"
maxTweets = 500
tweetsPerQry = 100

tweets = api.search(q=searchW, count=tweetsPerQry, geocode="51.5128,-0.1171,2km")
for tweet in tweets:
    if tweet.coordinates is not None:
        lon = tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][0]
        lat = tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][1]
        print('lat', lat, 'lon', lon)
    print(tweet.user.id_str, tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.text, tweet.coordinates)
```